# Wanting to write an app for surface pro tablet

Tags: windows-8, surface

1. i want to write an app for surface pro tablet ( but not for the windows 8 rt, where do i start as there are much information available. are their any book to which i can refer to?
2. how do it differ from writing an app for the Windows 8?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Obviously, you don't have a specific programming problem but a rather broad request for books or tutorials. In this case it is better to ask Google.

Comment: Yes. Like you've suggested I have been at it for few days but couldn't find any book on Surface Application. All that's few available are for Windows store app. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Store apps work for all tablets (ecen on devices without touch), not only the Surface. Run Visual Studio and create a new [Windows Store App project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh768232.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the help. One simple silly question, how different are they at the core ( app for windows store and app for surface native) both in terms of functionality and also look and feel wise.

Comment: what do you mean with " app for surface native"?